Java decryption throw strange error with simplest test case
How could this happen ?
This code can't decrypt the "encrypted" text of the string "hello". I searches similar threads but I still can't understand.
public class Test {

    class Encryption {
        File file;
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;


        public void setFile(String filePathResource) throws Exception {
            URL url = Encryption.class.getResource(filePathResource);
            System.out.println(url.toString());
            this.file = new File(url.toURI());
            if (!file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File is not valid");
                throw new Exception("The file you choosed is not valid");
            }
        }

        public void setKey(String keyword) {
            try {
                MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                //sha.update(keyword.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                sha.update(keyword.getBytes());
                byte[] key = sha.digest();
                secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public String encryptText(String text) {
            byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
            //String encodedResul = null;
            try {
                byte[] bytesText = text.getBytes();
                
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
                encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(bytesText);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new String(encryptedBytes);
        }

        
                
        public String decryptText(String encryptedText) {
            byte[] decryptedBytes = null;
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // byte[] bytesEncryptedText = encryptedText.getBytes("UTF-8");
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
                //byte[] decodedEncryptedText=Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText);
                byte[] encryptedTextBytes=encryptedText.getBytes();
                decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);    

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new String(decryptedBytes);
        }

        
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        
        Test t = new Test();
        Encryption cipher = t.new Encryption();

        cipher.setKey("password");

         //String  encryptedText=cipher.encryptText("2024-05-04T05:48:19.702630400Z[UTC]");
         //String  encryptedText=cipher.encryptText("11-24'?*&11[]");
         String  encryptedText=cipher.encryptText("hello");
         System.out.println(new String(encryptedText));
         
         
//       char[]cl= encryptedText.toCharArray();
//       int i=1;
//       for(char c:cl) {
//           System.out.println(i++ + ". " +c);
//       }
        
        
         System.out.println(cipher.decryptText(encryptedText));
    }

}


The code works well with an complicate text as "11-24'?*&11[]" but with a simple text "hello" it broken.
Can any expert explain this ?
"11-24'?*&11[]" ===> work well
|Ä{™úk©¢­[ÁÌ­¿
µ
11-24'?*&11[]
"hello" ===> broken
iî]´¾-Ò?%??H
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:859)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:939)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:735)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2205)
    at t$Encryption.decryptText(t.java:113)
    at t.main(t.java:174)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "bytes" is null
    at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:1432)
    at t$Encryption.decryptText(t.java:118)
    at t.main(t.java:174)
`


new String(encryptedBytes) corrupts the ciphertext. Use the binary data itself, or, if you want to convert the binary data to a string, use a binary-to-text encoding like Base64.

Be careful with using getBytes() and the constructor new String(byte[]) as the charset is the default one from the current system, which can be different on different hosts.

...I already give up on Base64 encoding... Then you have used it incorrectly. If I use Base64 in your code, it works. Post your code with the Base64 encoding/decoding.

Does this answer your question? Cannot convert String to byte array and vice versa in Java

I already give up on Base64 encoding, tried it. The charset hint UTF-8 also didn't solve the problem. I just want to run this test on windows platform and using the default's charset. How this strange error could happen ? The new String(encryptedBytes) corrupts the ciphertext of "hello", but it doesn't corrupt the ciphertext of "11-24'?*&11[]" ?

Have a look at this post, which explains very well why charset encodings are generally not suitable for ciphertexts. If the problem is still not clear, post what your default encoding is (probably UTF-8).

@mmofood Ciphertext is randomized. If you try and decode it as if it is text then some bytes may be removed. Or you might simply keep the ciphertext around as bytes, quite often those kind of encodings are not necessary at all. You are using ECB = insecure, SHA-256 as a PBKDF, also insecure.

@Topaco, Maarten Bodewes Thank you all, this problem is  solved. I used Base64 encoder/decoder for avoiding byte loss  in case of UTF-8.

This might help
Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
Overall you need to ensure that you are safely transmitting your encrypted information. The standard toString() method can corrupt your data which is most likely what's happening in your case.
I have modified the encrypt and decrypt methods and attaching the snippets.
Hope it works for you !!
public String encryptText(String text) {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
        //String encodedResul = null;
        try {
            byte[] bytesText = text.getBytes();

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(bytesText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Safely Encode string
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
    }


    public String decryptText(String encryptedText) {
        byte[] decryptedBytes = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            //Safely decode string
            byte[] encryptedTextBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText);
            decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new String(decryptedBytes);
    }
}


Thank you very much. It works flawlessly. The key is Just two lines of code : Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes) Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText)
